# Selenium WebDriver with C# using NUnit: execute test cases on multiple browsers in parallel on single machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, selenium, webdriver, nunit

I am new in Selenium testing. I want to run my multiple test cases on different browsers in single machine.

I have windows 7 operating system with Visual Studio 2010 installed. I am using Selenium IDE + WebDriver + NUnit.

I want to run my test cases on different browsers in single machine in parallel.

Let's say I have T1, T2 and T3 test cases, recorded in Selenium IDE, and IE 8, FireFox and Chrome Browser Install on my machine. I want to run T1 >> on IE 8, FireFox and Chrome Browser at the same time, in parallel.

Please let me know

**what are the software I need to install/configure to achive** 
and how to do it.

Step by Step details of configuration will really help me as I am new to Selenium and as well as to Open Source testing World.

Appreciate your quick reply.

Thanks,
AJain

Comment: Are you familiar with how to use NUnit, and run a simple test?

Comment: Use Selenium Grid to do it all in parallel, otherwise just use parameterised NUnit tests if you do not need it in parallel. Parameterised NUnit Tests: quicker to set up, easier to get going but slower as the next browser would not be opened until the previous one is closed. Selenium Grid: faster as you can do it all in parallel, but requires a little bit of knowledge base digging and set up - also need to ensure your CI server can handle the extra load if it's all done in parallel.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I am trying to learn NUnit using available material on blogs. I have run few test in Nunit. I integrated the NUnit in my VS2010 as a external tool and using it for running simple tests.
Not able to run test on different browser at the same time.

Comment: Thanks Arran, I have limitd knowledge of Grid. I'll try to learn grid
. I have worked on QTP, VSTS coded UI test testing tools but none of this tool support parallel testing.

Comment: quick question, any open source tool support parallel testing...?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Packages is needed to be installed in any of the technology you are using such as C#/Java/Delphi

```
Install-Package Selenium.WebDriver
Install-Package WebDriverChromeDriver
Install-Package NUnitTestAdapter.WithFramework 
Install-Package WebDriver.IEDriver
Install-Package Selenium.Support
```

Install nunit Click on [Download](http://github.com/nunit/nunitv2/releases/download/2.6.4/NUnit-2.6.4.msi)

Let me know if any other guidance is needed

Answer (score 0):

You May want to Try Out BrowserStack -
http://browserstack.com/